# Would past simple be ok in this case

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

10. Complete the passage with the correct form of the verbs in brackets.

Goldilocks is probably the most famous and most charming “squatter” of all times.While the Bear family was looking(look)for breakfast, Goldilocks broke into(break into)their house and made (make)herself at home. The first thing she saw (see)when she **had entered** (enter)the house was food on the table.

I know past perfect is here to emphasize the completion of the action of entering but would past simple fit as well

Comment: It's incorrect to say "of all times." You would say "the most charming 'squatter' of all time."

Answer (score 1):

"The first thing she saw (see)when she entered (enter)the house was food on the table." : YES, it's perfect.
Simple Past is a better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple past, the two actions, entering the house and seeing the food, happen at the same time, or the seeing happens shortly (a few seconds perhaps) after the entering, which I think is possible. If you use past perfect you emphasize that first she entered the house (in the past) before she saw the food (in the past). I don't think past perfect is necessary here.